# Topological vector spaces with $0$-neighbourhood base of von Neumann-bounded sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space, s.t. there exists a $0$-neighbourhood (sub-)base of von Neumann-bounded subsets. Do such spaces have a name?

Comment: In the locally convex Hausdorff case these are precisely the normed (or normable) spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a topological vector space is called "locally bounded".  Note that any subset of a bounded set is bounded, so actually it suffices for there to exist just a single bounded neighborhood of $0$.